# Passing SQL operators to query through iReport Parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to create a report in iReport based on an oracle SQL query which deals with transactions. The actual tables involved are very lengthy and are not really relevant to the issue. I am trying to create a report that will return results when the transaction amounts meet 1 of the 3 following criteria:

- between 1000.00 and 2499.99
- between 2500.00 and 9999.99
- >= 10000.00

I am trying to create a single select list parameter where the person running the report can choose between one of the above specifications. Before I actually create the parameter I have been trying to test the query in SQL Developer. The line  of the query where I am trying to implement this is:

```
alias.transaction_amount :amountRange
```

and my test input is "between 1000 and 9999". When that is hardcoded in the query, it works fine, but when I try and pass it in through this input I get an "Invalid Relational Operator" error.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Is your :amountRange a string? Are you trying to use a single parameter for the whole expression 'between 1000.00 and 2499.99'? Then you need to test the same thing in SQL and see... I do not know much about iReports, but it looks like you want to build dynamic where clause using some expression, which will not work in SQL. In Oracle reports there are Lexical parameters for this. Maybe there is smth. similar in your iReports...

Comment: yes the :amountRange is a string and it is the whole expression. But I see, I didn't think it would be supported but I figured it would be worth a shot, however maybe there is a chance that iReport does support this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this in query: 
select ... from table1 where transaction_amount $P!{paramReport}

From JasperReports Ultimate Guide:

```
$P{paramName} Syntax
The parameters are used like normal java.sql.PreparedStatement parameters, using
the following syntax:
<queryString>
<![CDATA[
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID <= $P{MaxOrderID} ORDER BY
ShipCountry
]]>
</queryString>

$P!{paramName} Syntax
Sometimes it is useful to use parameters to dynamically modify portions of the SQL
query or to pass the entire SQL query as a parameter to the report-filling routines. In
such cases, the syntax differs a little, as shown in the following example. Notice the !
character:
<queryString>
<![CDATA[
SELECT * FROM $P!{MyTable} ORDER BY $P!{OrderByClause}
]]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: So if I were to utilize this syntax, would I have to put the entire where clause in the parameter? Or could I narrow it down to just
    alias.transaction_amount $P!{Amount_Range}
? Thank you for you response

Answer (score 0):

After talking with some colleagues, we discovered a better solution to this problem, while I don't know if the method I was looking for is actually possible, this solution is much more intuitive.

```
alias.transaction_amount between (CASE WHEN $P{Range} = 0
                                       THEN 1000.00
                                       WHEN $P{Range} = 1
                                       THEN 2500.00
                                       ELSE 10000.00
                                       END)
                                 and
                                 (CASE WHEN $P{Range} = 0
                                       THEN 2499.99
                                       WHEN $P{Range} = 1
                                       THEN 9999.99
                                       ELSE 9999999.99
                                       END)
```

Using case statements with a switch parameter works perfectly, granted that if there's ever a transaction which is 1 billion dollars or greater they will be excluded but the maximum number can be adjusted as necessary.