# optional where clause jasper reports

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am trying this query but without success.

```
SELECT name, phone_office, billing_address_city, billing_address_street, billing_address_country 
FROM accounts
WHERE ($P!{EmployeeID} is null or assigned_user_id = $P!{EmployeeID})
ORDER BY billing_address_country, billing_address_city
```

This url will filter by EmployeeID and works fine:

```
.../flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/samples/EmployeeAccounts&EmployeeID=sarah_id
```

But when i remove the EmployeeID parameter i want to remove the filter where. So all results should be shown.

```
.../flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/samples/EmployeeAccounts
```

My question is, what is the correct way of passing an optional where in sql query.

Comment: `$P!{EmployeeID}` 

is it a field name or some data?

Comment: @Shann EmployeeID is a parameter

Comment: yup i know it is a parameter, but are you supplying table name or data?
as from the query `WHERE $P!{EmployeeID} is null` , the parameter should supply table name.
and here `assigned_user_id = $P!{EmployeeID}` it should supply data.
i guess your query itself is not correct

Comment: can you show your data from table accounts
and what is your desired output from query

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing empty field as parameter in jasper ireport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460446/passing-empty-field-as-parameter-in-jasper-ireport) & [JasperServer - null values for input controls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11082379/876298)

Comment: @AlexK, if so, what is the answer?

Comment: Why you use P!{par} instead P{par}? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145575/passing-sql-operators-to-query-through-ireport-parameter/15151942#15151942](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145575/passing-sql-operators-to-query-through-ireport-parameter/15151942#15151942)

Comment: @AlexK Just to clarify, i want to know how can i remove the where if the url doesn have &EmployeeID=sarah_id

Comment: from my pov @anvd is passing parameter instead of field name, and the using the same parameter to filter in assigned_user_id field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, let see the sample.

For example we have a query:

```sql
SELECT id, city, street FROM address WHERE city=$P{inputParamCity} ORDER BY city
```

But our ***inputParamCity*** can be undefined. In this case we got an error:

```
Error filling print... Error preparing statement for executing the report query : 
SELECT id, city, street FROM address WHERE city=? ORDER BY city
```

How we can fix it?
 
It is very simple - we can add another parameter with default expression like this:

```xml
<parameter name="whereClause" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[()$P{inputParamCity} == null || $P{inputParamCity}.isEmpty()) ? "1=1" : "city='" + $P{inputParamCity} + "'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

-if the *inputParamCity* parameter is undefined the "fake" clause *"1=1"* will be used, in other case the filter by *city* field will be applied.

And of course we have to modify the query expression - to use this new parameter. Our query expression in this case will be:

```xml
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT id, city, street FROM address WHERE $P!{whereClause} ORDER BY city]]>
</queryString>
```

#### The sample

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="optional_where_clause" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d3648644-0087-4dfc-ac6d-87e82d9bb33e">
    <parameter name="inputParamCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="whereClause" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[($P{inputParamCity} == null || $P{inputParamCity}.isEmpty()) ? "1=1" : "city='" + $P{inputParamCity} + "'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, city, street FROM address WHERE $P!{whereClause} ORDER BY city]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c2a80b99-e087-4839-8e77-841edd899255" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="0aafcfd6-60f7-4272-8e7d-0aa77507204b" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c8726513-8250-43ec-bafc-003e81094c27" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

In case using undefined *inputParamCity* parameter (the value is not set) the result will be:

[image]

In this case the query was used by engine is:

```sql
SELECT id, city, street FROM address WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY city
```

If we set, for example, the value ***Chicago*** for *inputParamCity* parameter the result will be:

[image]

In this case the query was used by engine is:

```sql
SELECT id, city, street FROM address WHERE city='Chicago' ORDER BY city
```

---

**Notes:**

- You can find more information in this post: [JasperReports: Passing parameters to query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871042/876298)
- You can modify the *whereClause* parameter's expression and the query expression. For example, you can move *WHERE* keyword from *query expression* to *parameter's expression* to prevent using the *fake* clause *"1=1"*

Comment: Be careful when you have two parameters in the where clause. In my case didn't with the same logic. Im using iReport 5.6

Answer (score 2):

I think optional where clause can be done in this way also :-

```
  SELECT name, phone_office, 
          billing_address_city, billing_address_street,
          billing_address_country 
  FROM accounts
  WHERE (assigned_user_id = $P{EmployeeID} or $P{EmployeeID} is null)
  ORDER BY billing_address_country, billing_address_city
```

In this condition if you do not pass any employee id it gives you all the values without applying where clause condition.